# Android, совет по реализации кастомной анимации

Tags: android, анимация, view

Задача по описанию простая. Есть `view`, у которого есть чёрная рамка. Хочу анимировать эту рамку, чтобы по ней с постоянной скоростью двигался небольшой кружок(xml/png, не суть дела). Как сделать подобное? Изучаю Android уже 2-3 месяца, но с анимациями вообще не сталкивался.

Гугл предоставляет мне следующие варианты.

1. Бахнуть в лоб `animation-list`. Не представляю как это вообще применимо для данной задачи, но в теории(в огромной такой теории) можно как - то извертеться. Анимация если и получится(что вряд ли), то она будет ужасной.
2. `ValueAnimator`/`ObjectAnimator`. Опять же в теории как - то можно будет это сюда приплести, менять положение точки за какое - то время. Только вот как реализовать пока не знаю, нет очевидной связи между `xml` и меняющейся переменной.
3. `TransitionManager`. Я так понял это совсем мимо, применяется скорее для нескольких объектов чем для атрибута одного объекта. Да и как применить тоже не ясно.

Особенность задачи в том, что мне не нужно управлять состоянием анимации, просто запустить её и всё. Я бы с радостью вообще её нарисовал бы как gif и как - нибудь запилил фоном, только вот про подобное я тоже ничего не нагуглил.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Кажется, в данном случае самый лучший способ просто рисовать на `canvas` с использованием `ValueAnimator`. `ValueAnimator` по своей сути просто может выдавать следующее значение из промежутка каждый раз при вызове Update. Его главная фитча это то, что к нему можно применять разные функции интерполяции из коробки. Сначала иожно просто нарисовать рамку, а затем в onDraw просто пересчитывать местоположение кружочка и отрисовывать его. Его 'координаты' можно пересчитывать через `ValueAnimator`. Кстати советую не забыть включить сглаживание, а то кружочек будет выглядеть рвано.

[Вот](https://proandroiddev.com/android-bring-life-to-your-custom-view-8604ab3967b3) статья по рисованию на канвасе с самых основ